# Angular 2: Can't add form group to form array in reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building dynamic form and want to add form groups 'on the fly'.

Here is my code which almost works:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators, FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

export class CombinedComponent implements OnInit {

    ltsForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ltsForm = this.initFormGroup();

        // init products
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // add dynamically products
            this.addProduct();
        }
        
        console.log(this.ltsForm); // Array 'prods' is empty
    }

    // initialize form group, but don't add products yet because they will be added dynamically later
    initFormGroup() {
        let group = this.formBuilder.group({
            products: this.initProductGroup()
        });

        return group;
    }

    initProductGroup() {
        let group = this.formBuilder.group(
            {
                //initialize empty formbuilder array
                prods: this.formBuilder.array([])
            }
        );

        return group;
    }

    initProducts() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [''],
            value: false, // checkbox value
        });
    }

    addProduct() {
        <FormArray>this.ltsForm.controls['products'].value.prods.push(this.initProducts());

        console.log(this.ltsForm); // Array 'prods' contains 3 FormGroup elements
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="ltsForm"
      novalidate
      (ngSubmit)="save(ltsForm)">

    <div formGroupName="products">
        <div formArrayName="prods">

            <div *ngFor="let product of ltsForm.controls.products.value.prods.controls; let i = index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           formControlName="value"
                           id="product_{{ i }}"
                           name="product_{{ i }}">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"
            [disabled]="!ltsForm.valid">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

In method `addProduct()` I push the whole FormGroup element to the 'prods' array. So at the end the output from console in `ngOnInit()` contains just an empty 'prods' array, while the array from console output in `addProduct()` method has 3 elements. It looks like `this.ltsForm` looses its reference and isn't updating. Any ideas?

UPD: Just found out that if I remove the whole content from template, I get the 'prods' filled with data.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There were a number of small mistakes and complexities, so I pared down your example and built it back up. The Angular team had examples of a [nested form array](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2a3ca7bfcfc4c861687eec252cc01ffc55796134/modules/%40angular/examples/forms/ts/nestedFormArray/nested_form_array_example.ts) and [nested form group](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2a3ca7bfcfc4c861687eec252cc01ffc55796134/modules/%40angular/examples/forms/ts/nestedFormGroup/nested_form_group_example.ts) that were very helpful. Here was the process (and [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fwWCwmXGXretngESd1WJ?p=info)):

1. Got a **simple group** working: `{ projects: '' }`.
2. Got a **group with an array of controls** working: `{ projects: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }`. I skipped `prods`, it seemed unnecessary.

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="ltsForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
     <div formArrayName="products">
       <div *ngFor="let p of products.controls; let i=index">
         <input [formControlName]="i">
       </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" [disabled]="!ltsForm.valid">
       Submit
     </button>
   </form>

   ...

   export class CombinedComponent implements OnInit {

     ltsForm: FormGroup;

     get products() { return this.ltsForm.get('products'); }

     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

     ngOnInit() {
         this.ltsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           products: this.formBuilder.array([])
         });

         for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
           this.addProduct();
         }
     }

     addProduct() {
       this.products.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
     }

     save() {
       console.log(this.ltsForm.value);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Final step replace controls in the **array with groups**:

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'combined-component',
     template: `
       <form [formGroup]="ltsForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
         <div formArrayName="products">
           <div *ngFor="let p of products.controls; let i=index">
             <div [formGroupName]="i">
               <input formControlName="id">
               <input type="checkbox" formControlName="value">
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" [disabled]="!ltsForm.valid">
             Submit
         </button>
       </form>
     `
   })
   export class CombinedComponent implements OnInit {

     ltsForm: FormGroup;

     get products() { return this.ltsForm.get('products'); }

     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

     ngOnInit() {
         this.ltsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           products: this.formBuilder.array([])
         });

         for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
           this.addProduct();
         }
     }

     addProduct() {
       this.products.push(this.formBuilder.group({
         id: '',
         value: false
       }));
     }

     save() {
       console.log(this.ltsForm.value);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, however I can't validate the whole form array. For example I have 3 products (checkboxes), and I need that at least 1 is checked. Then I will have another form array with materials checkboxes, where also at least 1 material should be selected.

Doing products: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required) doesn't work, so that was the reason I wanted to create at first  form group, then validate it, and within that form group add form array.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

Using this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)  is wrong, because 'Validators.required' validates if the value is empty or not. In case of Array it will be always validated, because array already exists. So therefore I must write custom validation function 'checkboxReqyured', and use it like this: products: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.compose([checkboxRequired]))

Comment: If form consist of nestead array(ex in above  case -> value[{"":""}] then how to build the form

Comment: @stealththeninja I followed your approach in my Angular application, I am getting an issue in binding controls using formControlName. Please have look into my posted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754073/getting-issue-in-registering-contorl-with-form-in-angular-reactive-forms