# Dynamically adding form fields using Angular formArray

Tags: angular

I have a few form fields and want to add more fields dynamically which is coming from another view(where user can enter the form field type, length and name), I Need to construct form fields using these values.

Some how i have managed to construct one field(`textbox name is 'one'`) but if i try to add another field(`textbox name is 'two'`) getting the following error saying,

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'newfields -> 0 -> two'
```

### issuecomponent.html

```
  <form [formGroup]="issuerTestCaseFrm">
                <div>
                    <label for="inputName3">Issuer Reference Number: </label>
                    <input name="lcid" formControlName="IssuerReferenceNumber" required type="tel" class="form-control">
                </div>
                    <div formArrayName="newfields">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let tech of issuerTestCaseFrm.controls.newfields.controls; let i = index">
                    <div *ngFor="let prop of fieldProps">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{fields[prop].label}}</label>
                                <div [ngSwitch]="fields[prop].type">
                                    <input *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [formControlName]="prop"> 
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
    </form>
<button type="submit" (click)="addNewInputField()"> &nbsp;Add New Column &nbsp; </button>
```

### issuecomponent.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Pipe, PipeTransform, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from '../../modal/modal.component';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'viewhistory',
  templateUrl: './issuecomponent.html',
})


export class IssuerTestcaseExecution implements OnInit {
  issuerTestCaseFrm: FormGroup;
  fields: any;
  fieldProps: any;
  formControls = {};
  constructor( 
    private fb: FormBuilder,  
    public modalService: NgbModal,
    ) {
    this.issuerTestCaseFrm = fb.group({
      'IssuerReferenceNumber': ['', Validators.required],
      'newfields': fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  initNewFields(): FormGroup {
    this.fieldProps.forEach(prop => {
      this.formControls[prop] = [this.fields[prop].value, Validators.required];
    });
    return this.fb.group(this.formControls);
  }

 //Assuming these results coming from modal view after add button click
  addNewInputField(): void {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
      modalRef.result.then((result) => {
         this.fields = {
          [result.fieldname]: {
            type: result.fieldtype,
            value: result.fieldvalue,
            label: result.fieldname,
          },
        };
        this.fieldProps = Object.keys(this.fields);
         const control = <FormArray>this.issuerTestCaseFrm.controls.newfields;
         control.push(this.initNewFields());
      }, (reason) => {

      });
  }
}
```

I have added sample code in stackblitz.com. can any body help on this issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-871vxk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

although this does not help you completely but there need some changes in form and component to remove this error

1. change form field to new FormArray()

   ```
    this.issuerTestCaseFrm = fb.group({
      'IssuerReferenceNumber': ['', Validators.required],
      'technologies': new FormArray([]),
   });
   ```
2. create getter of form filed `technologies` in the component file.

   ```
   get technologies(): FormArray { return this.issuerTestCaseFrm.get('technologies') as FormArray; }
   ```
3. in HTML use this way, add formArrayname along with `*ngFor` and add [formControlName]="i" in your input field.

   ```
   <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let tech of technologies.controls; let i = index" formArrayName="technologies">

   <input class="form-control" *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [formControlName]="i">
   ```
4. when you click to add button use `control.push(new FormControl())`

now here you have to work how to add complete formfield

here is the [updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcvc5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[Angular FormArray Reference](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName)

Comment: I have checked but getting the error in  console saying, ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: my intention is need to generate dynamic [formControllerName]. so that i can directly send the parameters to database. i stuck up here, kindly look into that issue.

Comment: as I said that my answer does not provide the complete solution. you need to work around how to set new formcontrol into your form. check angular form reference.