# Adding new dynamic form controller using angular 4 reactive form

Tags: angular

I have a angular form with different fields and need to add dynamic fields while clicking on the `ADD` button. And i am storing the dynamic parameters(which is coming from modal dialog) in the JSON object in the following way,

**I have added sample code in `stackblitz`, can any one help on this.** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-871vxk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
this.fields = {
          [result.fieldname]: {
            type: result.fieldtype, //fieldtype='text'
            value: result.fieldvalue, //fieldvalue = ''
            label: result.fieldname, //fieldname = 'First field'
          },
        };
```

I have gone through many articles and found only static fields can add using `formArray` in the following way. But how do i add many different fields using reactive form controller.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

   public form          : FormGroup;


   constructor(public navCtrl       : NavController,
               public navParams     : NavParams,
               private _FB          : FormBuilder)
   {

      this.form = this._FB.group({
         name             : ['', Validators.required],
         technologies     : this._FB.array([
            this.initTechnologyFields()
         ])
      });
   }


   initTechnologyFields() : FormGroup
   {
      return this._FB.group({
         name       : ['', Validators.required]
      });
   }

   addNewInputField() : void
   {
      const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls.technologies;
      control.push(this.initTechnologyFields());
   }
}
```

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Comment: @indrakumara, I have done some of the work and able to create one form field using formArray. But I try to add another form controller getting error. I have created stack overflow link. Could you help on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054638/dynamically-adding-form-fields-using-angular-formarray

Comment: @Indrakumara, I have added code in stackblitz.com. could you please help on this issue:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-871vxk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have changed your code to get the result : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zppqkp