# Nested Form Group triggeres change detection multiple times

Tags: typescript, angular9, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517389/angular-2-cant-add-form-group-to-form-array-in-reactive-forms) as a reference, i have replicated the dynamic nested form group creation using reactive forms.

But it triggers the change detection multiple times, when adding a new form group into an form array.

> my code

component.html

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="addMaterial()">Add</button>

<form [formGroup]="positionFormGroup" novalidate>
  <table formArrayName="positionInfos">

    <div *ngFor="let data of Controls.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">

        <input type="text" formControlName="idMaterial" [matAutocomplete]="materialAuto">
        <mat-autocomplete #materialAuto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of materialFilteredOptions | async" [value]="option.description">
            {{option.description}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </div>
    </div>

  </table>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  positionFormGroup: FormGroup;
  materialControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
  materialFilteredOptions: Observable<{ description: string; }[]>;
  options = [
    { description: 'item1' },
    { description: 'item2' },
    { description: 'item3' },
    { description: 'item4' }
  ]
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.materialFilteredOptions = this.materialControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this.options)
      );
    this.positionFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      positionInfos: new FormArray([])
    });

    this.addMaterial();

  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log('triggered');
  }

  addMaterial() {
    (this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.group({
      rowID: '0',
      position: '0',
      idMaterial: 'item1',
      quantity: 1,
      isDeleted: false,
      isActive: true
    }));
  }

  confirm(){
    console.log( this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos').value)
  }

  get Controls(){
    console.log( (this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos') as FormArray));
    return (this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos') as FormArray);
     
  }
}
```

Shared the console as well. when i am adding the new form group into the form array, it was happening.
I am not getting why it was triggering the change detection multiple times.

[image: Console info]

Please let me know, if i am missing something. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, i got an answer. Whenever change detection is happening, template is re-evaluates the method.

Instead of **Controls getter**, directly used a class property to get the nested form group control.

**ts**

```
  this.control = this.getControls().controls;

  getControls(){
    console.log( (this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos') as FormArray));
    return (this.positionFormGroup.get('positionInfos') as FormArray);
  }
```

**html**

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of control; let i = index">
```

Answer (score 0):

I should change ChangeDetectionStrategy to onPush, so component will be rendered only once

```
@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  templateUrl: "./hello.component.html",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

[your working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrivdb)